# React-Rendering a 2 dimensional array

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I try to select a specific button rendered from a 2d array, it ends up selecting all rendered buttons. Is there a way to render the lower details for one specific button.

```
<Grid container>
        {this.serviceByLangauge.map((cat, id) => (
          <Grid
            item
            xs={4}
            key={cat.id}
            className={this.props.classes.categoryGroup}
          >
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              size="medium"
              color="primary"
              className={this.props.classes.services}
              onClick={this.showServices.bind(this, cat.services)}
              key={cat.id}
            >
              {cat.name}
            </Button>
            <div className={this.props.classes.serviceGroup}>
              {servicesList.length > 0 ? (
                <List>
                  {servicesList.map((serv, id) => (
                    <ListItem key={id}>
                      <ListItemText primary={id + 1 + ") " + serv.name} />
                    </ListItem>
                  ))}
                </List>
              ) : (
                <div></div>
              )}
            </div>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
```

[image: list of buttons[![]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QlKr.png)

Comment: Where does `servicesList` come from? The data it contains seems to be the same for each iteration.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EQAPa3O

Comment: Where is the call to `showServices()` ?

Comment: in the image, right before render. it's to update the components status

Comment: When you click on one button, the content underneath every button is set to the content that you only want to be shown under the button that was clicked, right?

Comment: exactly, how do I make it render underneath the button that selected it

Comment: I've posted a possible solution as answer.

Answer (score 1):

can you show us the data of the 2d array?

**edit:**

I guess you're not iterating `servicesList`.

Try this instead:

```
<Grid container>
        {this.serviceByLangauge.map((cat, id) => (
          <Grid
            item
            xs={4}
            key={cat.id}
            className={this.props.classes.categoryGroup}
          >
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              size="medium"
              color="primary"
              className={this.props.classes.services}
              onClick={this.showServices.bind(this, cat.services)}
              key={cat.id}
            >
              {cat.name}
            </Button>
            <div className={this.props.classes.serviceGroup}>
              {cat.services.length > 0 ? (
                <List>
                  {cat.services.map((serv, id) => (
                    <ListItem key={id}>
                      <ListItemText primary={id + 1 + ") " + serv.name} />
                    </ListItem>
                  ))}
                </List>
              ) : (
                <div></div>
              )}
            </div>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
```

Comment: ``list= [
    {
      name: "SIM CARD SERVICES",
      id: 1,
      services: [
        {
          name: "SIM REPLACEMENT",
          initial: "SR"
        },
        {
          name: "PIN/PUK",
          initial: "SP"
        },
        {
          name: "SIM CARD ISSUES",
          initial: "SI"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "BUY",
      id: 2,
      services: [
        {
          name: "BUY",
          initial: "BB"
        }
      ]
    },```

Comment: this is not complete, where are you setting `servicesList`?

Comment: my edit is working, see this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-bush-ykc12

please do not share code as screenshots!

Answer (score 0):

From the images and the source code you provided, I think to following is wrong:

**You derive the services to show from your state**. In your state, you have only one list of services. When clicking a button, **you update the state with the services of the button**.

```js
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              size="medium"
              color="primary"
              className={this.props.classes.services}
              onClick={this.showServices.bind(this, cat.services)}
              key={cat.id}
            >
```

Then you iterate on this same state for every button:

```js
            <div className={this.props.classes.serviceGroup}>
              {servicesList.length > 0 ? (
                <List>
                  {servicesList.map((serv, id) => (
                    <ListItem key={id}>
                      <ListItemText primary={id + 1 + ") " + serv.name} />
                    </ListItem>
                  ))}
                </List>
              ) : (
                <div></div>
              )}
            </div>
```

I think you want to iterate over `cat` instead of `serviceList`:

```js
            <div className={this.props.classes.serviceGroup}>
              {cat.length > 0 ? (
                <List>
                  {cat.map((serv, id) => (
                    <ListItem key={id}>
                      <ListItemText primary={id + 1 + ") " + serv.name} />
                    </ListItem>
                  ))}
                </List>
              ) : (
                <div></div>
              )}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a condition to make sure that I'm only rendering the div when category id's match

```
 if (this.state.showThis) {
      servicesComponent = (
        <List className={this.props.classes.serviceGroup}>
          {this.state.services.map((serv, id) => (
            <ListItem key={id}>
              <ListItemText primary={id + 1 + ") " + serv[langCode]} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      );
    } else {
      servicesComponent = <div></div>;
    }

    const categories = servicesAndCategories.map((category, index) => (
      <Grid
        item
        xs={4}
        className={this.props.classes.categoryGroup}
        key={index}
      >
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          size="medium"
          color="primary"
          className={this.props.classes.services}
          onClick={this.showServices.bind(this, category.services, category.id)}
        >
          {category[langCode]}
        </Button>
        {this.state.currentCategory === category.id && servicesComponent}
      </Grid>
    ));
``
```